# google-plus application for android 1.6?

Tags: 1.6-donut, google-plus

Is there a google-plus application for Android 1.6? My device won't be updated to 2.0+, so unless someone writes a 1.6 compatible app, I'm stuck without it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The official [Google+ app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.apps.plus) requires Android 2.1 or newer, and as the market share for 1.6 and older is now vanishingly small, and getting smaller by the day (at time of writing the [combined market share of 1.5 + 1.6 is 3.6%](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html)) it's unlikely to be modified to work on older OSs. Similarly unless there's a dev who's also stuck on 1.6 himself and desperate to use Google+, a market share like that is barely worth most Devs efforts to create a 3rd party app if there's features in newer platform versions that would make things easier for them.

Your best bet is to use the web interface at http://google.com/+ as the [Google+ for mobile page](http://www.google.com/mobile/+/) specifically states that that is compatible with Android 1.5 and up.

Answer (score 4):

You have 2 main options:

1) Use web based Google+ through your browser
2) OR, root your phone and put a custom ROM that has android v2.1 or higher.

If you are willing to do the latter, then google around or search here on

http://forum.xda-developers.com

find your device in the master list, and try to find root and rom instructions there. Chances are, if you have a G1, My Touch, Cliq or any of the old devices, you will find instructions on how to get a 2.1+ ROM

Happy rooting! :)

Answer (score 0):

Mhhh...
This is gonna be impossible / tricky...

I'd say:

a) Check if you have any custom ROM developed for your phone (cyanogen & co) so you can upgrade not officially your android version

b) Wait for seesmic and similar application to support google+ and use one of those

c) Use the web version (but I suppose you do not like it)

If you give further information about your android I'll try to be much more specific :)

Comment: I've suggested to use the web application too :/

Comment: The Internet is so unfair! :P